# Authentication requied. You need to sign in google play account. in in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an error

> Authentication requied. You need to sign in google play account.

while testing in-app billing on my device with testing account.

I have implemented in-app billing v3 and i have uploaded **signed** apk in developer console as draft apk and running higher version signed apk in my device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login into Play with the same account which is added as Test Account into developer account.

From [Testing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html)

5 .  ***Login to the test device by using a tester account.*** Test your In-app Billing application by purchasing a few items, and fix any issues that you encounter. Remember to refund the purchases if you don’t want your testers to be actually charged!

---

As you said you logged in with the same user id, then problem might be [Getting “Authentication is required” when trying to access the market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-market)

Comment: Is that account is primary account?

Comment: how to check primary account?

Comment: Open Play app and try to open any paid app (not for dowanload). Check if Play recognize your test account. Better is remove all accounts other than test account and then check. See updated answer also

Comment: i am able to buy paid apps

Answer (score 0):

It might be a temporary error.

I just implemented the v3 billing API in one of my apps and got the same error message. I followed the TrivialDrive example and uploaded my app for testing. Last night it worked fine, but today when trying to test a purchase I got the same error message you did. I then closed the error message and retried the purchase and it was working again? It might be my implementation of Billing that is incorrect or there might be a bug in the Google example code.

I'm going to continue testing before releasing my app but I'll be interested to hear if you find a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my Android tablet and though I kept going into my settings to reset the new password, the same message kept coming up.  Finally, I found that I needed to open the 'warning message' that was being sent to me.  Only then did it 'take' the new password and allow me to use Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could occur because you don`t have added the product that you are searching with the same ID added to Google Play.

Go to `In-app Products` menu and check the product ID or add any one.